# Android "managed device" recognized as mass storage device. adb doesn't see device. How do I do I determine drivers?

Tags: applications, adb, rooting, root-access, installation

I have an android "managed device" that seems to have been some company tablet. No discernible brand. When I boot, it gives a screen with only a settings app. The settings app is very slimmed down, without access to debugging tools.

Debugging should be allowed by default on this device, because from what I understand, apps were installed and uninstalled from a company kiosk. Therefor, debugging would have had to been enabled.

It is a mediatek device with VID_0E8D. It's got pretty nice hardware. I'd like to be able to at least install apps on it, if not root it and re-install android.

It seems to have locked boot loader.

How to I figure out which drivers I need on windows 7 to recognize it as an android device? android studio nor adb can see it, but I can access the file system. Not the .android system files, just a few redundant files and folders that show up.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: As long as you have not managed to enable an USB protocol drivers are not relevant for you. I would try to get into bootloader or recovery system by pressing vol up/down and power or other key combinations while booting. May be you encounter a screen that shows hardware details.

Comment: enable usb-debugging and set usb connection to MTP in developer options. check windows device manager, pick android device, install android_winusb.inf https://developer.android.com/studio/run/win-usb

Comment: @Robert thanks for the response. It has a locked bootloader, and using power/vol up/down doesn't get me into bios. I'm an experienced web developer, so I have a bit of overall experience. However, unlocking bootloader and/or bypassing security on android devices is somewhat new to me. Do you have any guidance or advice as to what  I could study or look into in order to start analyzing what I need to do to unlock the bootloader or any other means to install new apps? I took it apart. It's a MTX chip, I have the details on that at least... Thanks again.

Comment: @Robert It appears to be very secure, being that I can't boot into firmware. Nor does settings allow me into the debugging section. Is there a way to possibly "hotwire" the board to get it to boot into the firmware?

Comment: May be - this depends on the board. Please not that your base assumption that debugging has to be enabled is totally wrong. App sideloading does not and never had anything to do with `adb`. The only relation between both is that on old regular devices both options were in the "Development options" menu.

Comment: @Robert I can't find any other way to sideload apps. Especially considering that the settings are so slimmed down. Any suggestions?

Comment: If the software is locked you have to directly address the hardware. Open the device, check for hardware debugging connections such as JTAG and read out the firmware for further analysis. Note that this is reverse engineering and therefore off-topic here. You may check https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Robert Thanks for the direction!